# ¿Cuál es la definición de albur? Could you define "albur"?

Tags: definiciones, méxico

Todos los que alguna vez hayan estado en México —y quizá en otros paises donde se practique el albur— saben que [la definición que da el DRAE](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1ZVdKVJ) para la palabra "albur" es paupérrima:

> 4. m. Méx. y R. Dom. Juego de palabras de doble sentido.

El artículo de [Wikipedia](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albur_(M%C3%A9xico)) tampoco es totalmente satisfactorio. En particular, se *axiomatiza* el albur de una manera rara, refiriéndose más a una competencia que a la práctica en la vida diaria.

¿Alguien tiene una mejor definición para albur?

Comment: this is a great question, anyone visiting mexico for more than a couple of days is sure to fall as an unwitting victim of "albures"... the answer is pretty good too!

Answer (score 6):

Te voy a contar lo me pasó una vez en un intento de expresar lo que creo que sea la esencia de un albur.

Hace un año me tocó ser maestro de inglés en una preparatoria, algo que no pretendo repetir, pero que sin embargo no fue sin chiste.

Un día en clase pasando entre los escritorios escuché un chamaco decir a otro *How do you say "I want to see drops" in spanish?*

Yo, queriendo ayudar, respondí la pregunta sin pensar, dije: Quiero ver gotas. Dicho rápido, quiero ver-gotas. (Verga = pene, vergota = un pene enorme).

Toda la clase se dobló de la risa y al final estuvo muy chistoso. Pero después cada vez que lo conté o que lo mencioné en la escuela siempre me decían **Te alburearon**.

Es un caso en que un sustantivo se usa como verbo, bastante común hoy en día, lo que me llevó a pensar que es un acto que haces a alguien, un juego en que participas. Sí como dice Newbie siempre tiene el sentido de algo sexual y erótico pero nada más quería añadir que no es solamente una forma de jerga, sino **una competencia de jerga**.

Por ejemplo, si buscas en Youtube *[Concurso de Albur](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=concurso%20de%20albur&oq=concurso%20de%20albur&gs_l=youtube.3...2993.7132.0.7256.23.16.1.1.1.3.527.2504.3-3j2j1.6.0...0.0...1ac.1.11.youtube.7xTJ15iYY74)* te salen algunos videos en que hay varias personas *albureándose*. Hasta hay un mini documental sobre [La Reina del albure](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2mkj_gWiL-4)

Answer (score 5):

El albur fino va más allá que el refrán popular, pues se apoya en la dualidad de la sexualidad recreada verbalmente con la picardía. Alburear es aprender a retorcer y exprimir el vocabulario para recrear el lado erótico del verbo, de manera concisa y contundente. En el barrio, alburear es un lenguaje escondido en las palabras.

Te dejo el [link](http://www.chilango.com/ciudad/nota/2013/03/01/silabario-del-albur) de donde saqué la info, la parte donde explica lo que es y cómo se hace es después del vídeo.

Answer (score 2):

Visitando el link que Newbie publicó, encontré este otro artículo de la misma revista *Chilango* que me parece define de una manera muy acertada lo que es el albur:

***" ¿Qué es el albur? 
Es ese juego del lenguaje muy mexicano, también llamado doble sentido, en el que tanto emisor como receptor establecen un diálogo entre líneas, por lo general sexual, que se parece más a un juego de palabras en el que el vencedor tendrá la última palabra. Agárrense (ya me los alburee). "***

***¿Por qué es bueno? 
Por si no lo sabes, el albur es una figura retórica harto original y creativa. Se compone por un parónimo, que son palabras que se oyen más o menos igual, pero significan distinto. Como recurso fonético, casi literario, es una joyita que no cualquiera puede emplear.***

Sí, en verdad es un juego que no termina hasta que hay un vencedor, lo cual puede ser muy avergonzante para el que resulte vencido. El albur va más allá del simple y llano doble sentido... es una esgrima del lenguaje que se puede convertir en una vergadera batalla de una gran envergadura, muy al estilo de los duelos de hip hop... jejeje y el que me la haya agarrado, que me busque la que rima con la jerga que comentan todos o los tres por aquí abajo, y ahí donde me la vean, me la paran y me le dan un beso... X^D

Ah pero eso sí, como bien lo dijo la Reina del Albur de Tepito: El buen albur no contiene ni una sola palabra altisonante... porque entonces ya no es albur sino guarrada.

El artículo se lo encuentran picando el siguiente [link](http://www.chilango.com/general/nota/2011/03/01/1-de-marzo-feliz-dia-del-albur) con lo que yo se que les va a gustar mucho ya que entre en materia... y me diculpo por la albureada pero es sólo para mostrar el sentido (o doble sentido) de lo que el albur es... así que con el artículo les pido muchas veces disculpas. =^D

Comment: And just as an additional note for our non-spanish readers... I did mispell "verdadera" intentionally... though it is part of the "albur" game... =^)

Answer (score 0):

Según la RAE, albur hace referencia al azar o la suerte y suele usarse en frases como "**no dejar nada al albur**".

También se refiere **a un pescado** "gris azulado por el dorso y plateado por el vientre, y cuyas huevas son muy estimadas" y que puede llegar a medir hasta 70 centímetros de longitud, es igualmente conocido como mújol.

De la misma forma, el término es empleado en otros países latinoamericanos como México, para referirse a **un juego de cartas o un juego de palabras**.