# ¿Cómo darme cuenta si alguien me está albureando?

Tags: coloquialismos, vulgaridades, humor

Tengo una idea de [lo que es el albur](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/3962/cual-es-la-definicion-de-albur-could-you-define-albur), pero aún batallo mucho con saber si alguien me está albureando.

¿Cómo puedo darme cuenta si una persona me está albureando? ¿Cuáles son las maneras más comunes de alburear?

Comment: http://mx.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20061027182802AAsD7FT

Answer (score 8):

Se necesita un buen dominio del idioma para darte cuenta que alguien te "alburea", es decir usan figuras retoricas como el doble sentido (Dilogía), la ironia, juego de palabras etc. para decirte algo, soliendo tener una connotación sexual (pero nunca soez) el verdadero significado, el Calambur.

Un ejemplo de doble sentido, sin connotacion sexual, seria:

- Imagina que alguien te dice: He reñido a un hostelero.
- Y tu le contestas: ¿Por qué? ¿dónde? ¿cuándo? ¿cómo?.
- La persona que te contesta, le dá la vuelta a tu pregunta y dice: Porque donde cuando como sirven mal, me desespero.

Un ejemplo de Albur:

- Creo que tengo la gripe aviar....¡¡¡Vieras qué tanto me moquea el pájaro!!!!

En este caso, con "me moquea el pájaro" tiene claras connotaciones sexuales. Aqui te estan albureando.

Entonces, ¿como darse cuenta? El tono jocoso en que se dice la frase debería darte una pista, luego buscar diferentes significados a la frase y ver que tengan sentido. Si el albur es muy complicado es posible que no le encuentres el doble sentido, se necesita práctica.

Comment: Pregunta. Entoces al alburear seria usar el doble sentido con una connotacion sexual?

Comment: En México alburear es únicamente con connotaciones sexuales.

Answer (score 4):

No sé que tan usado sea el albur en otros paises, pero en México es usado a diario y yo diría que con mucha frecuencia. Es usado generalmente entre amigos o en general con gente de confianza en ánimo de camaradería y relajo. El objetivo principal del albur en México es hacer mofa o burla de una persona mediante el uso de palabras cotidianas pero que en un doble sentido están cargadas de connotaciones sexuales. Dada la naturaleza del albur, las posibilidades son tan variadas como extenso es el lenguaje castellano. 
En mi opinión, no hay manera a ciencia cierta de saber cuando estás siendo albureado salvo ganando experiencia en dicho terreno. Sin embargo, existe un conjunto de palabras y/o frases recurrentes a la hora de alburear, por lo tanto es básico conocerlas para tener una idea un poco mas acertada para poder detectar cuando uno está siendo víctima del albur o incluso para tener mayor certeza y animarse así a responder el albur. Aquí enlisto dichas palabras/frases recurrentes en los albures:

> **Verbos recurrentes:**
>
> Sentar, arrimar, meter, sacar, lamer, chupar, embarrar, picar, sumir,
>   echar.
>
> **Del miembro viríl:**
>
> Macana, garrote, pájaro, chile, pirata, cíclope, pelón, chorizo,
>   longaniza, plátano, salchicha, verdura, negra, pistola, corneta, leño,
>   ñonga.
>
> **De orificios corporales:**
>
> Papaya, panocha, chango, chico, anís, anillo.
>
> **De sustancias expelidas por el cuerpo:**
>
> Blanco, leche, crema, café, cacahuate, calabaza, pedazo, pedestal,
>   frijoles.

Usando este mini glosario, aquí algunos ejemplos de albures:

> -arrimar el chile
>
> -sacar leche
>
> -arrimar el chico
>
> -sacar frijoles

Estas frases y palabras usadas para alburear expuestas aquí son específicamente aplicadas en México, no tengo idea realmente de su uso en este sentido en otros paises.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que puedes aprender viendo el siguiente video donde [alburean a la bailarina española Raquel Ortega](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4rk8LvQsbeM), jueza de Pequeños Gigantes, cuando vino a México. Te listo gran parte de ellos:

- Por favor mandale un saludo a mi primo Elber Galarga: El verga larga
- Elma Canon: El macananon
- Alma Madero: Al mamadero
- Rosa Melgorro: Rosame el gorro
- Rosa Melano: Rosame el ano
- Benito Camela: Ven y tocamela (la verga)
- Raspado de anis: Raspado de ano.
- Lomas Ajeo: lo masajeo (el pene)
- ¿Quieres a Carlos?: ¿Quieres sacarlos (los penes)?
- Juancho Talarga: Juancho esta larga
- ¿Te gusto el queso plabas?: ¿Te gusto el (pene) que soplabas?
- Saludos desde San Goloteas: zangoloteas (los pechos o los testiculos)
- ¿Te gustó el queso babas?: ¿Te gustó el (pene) que sobabas?
- Elber Gonzalez: El vergon
- Paty Lacabezona: Para ti la cabezona (la verga)
- Paloma Maria: Lo mamaria (el pene)
- Rosa Celeste: Rosas el este
- Melpico: Me pico (la vagina o el ano)

Quizá falten algunos mas porque inclusive como nativo puedes no entender a la primera el albur (doble sentido). Como te podras dar cuenta todos tienen connotación sexual.

Answer (score 2):

Hay que prestar atención a los verbos cuando éstos impliquen el contacto con otra persona o cosa. Cosas como:

> Jugar, tocar, comer, saborear, meter, agarrar, tomar, beber, chupar, raspar, restregar, besar, lamer... etc.

Son muchísimas formas en las que pueden darle la vuelta a cualquier comentario para alburearte.

Tienes que prestar mucha atención a las palabras por ejemplo:

> -Agárrame la ... [interrupción]
>
> -Agárrame ésta

Se podría decir que esta es de las formas más comunes de alburear a alguien.

> Pásame la cosa esa... sin albur.
>
> -Ok, ok, yo me imaginaba otra cosa.

Otro ejemplo:

> -Préstame tu anillo porfa.
>
> -Oye, oye, ey cuidado, ese no lo presto que es sólo mío.

Uno más:

> -¿No quieres un raspado de anís?
>
> -Que pasó, yo no soy así.

En cuanto a las palabras cualquier con casi puede significar sexo, genitales o cualquier otra cosa relacionada con ésto.