# ¿Es "Hola cara de pez" un saludo en México? ¿Qué significa?

Tags: expresiones, méxico, significado, saludos

Me han saludado diciéndome eso.
Yo le he preguntado que por qué me decía eso. Y me respondió que es un saludo de México.
Y me pregunto si es verdad y qué significado tiene

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a [Spanish.SE]! Una curiosa cuestión. Yo soy de España y si me dijeran eso la verdad es que no sabría cómo tomármelo. Esperemos que alguien de México pueda arrojar luz al asunto.

Answer (score 3):

Sí, es un saludo. Tiene la intención de ser un poco gracioso sin implicar nada importante en absoluto. No es una ofensa, es simplemente una forma de saludar de manera muy informal, amistosa y graciosa.

Lo importante acá es que el saludo no es en sí `"cara de pez"`. El saludo es una formula que va así:

> Hola cara de [*algo gracioso ya sea porque es absurdo o por que es muy grosero*].

Ejemplos de algunas variaciones que google autocomplete ofrece al escribir `Hola cara de`:

> Hola cara de bola / cola / papa / mono / moco.

Es importante señalar que un saludo así no se una para ofender a alguien, solo para ser gracioso con alguien de mucha confianza y buen sentido del humor.

Un saludo común entre mis amigos (somos Colombianos) es:

> ¡Hola care' culo! (cara de -> care').

Y la formula puede llevarse a complejidades extremas:

> Hola care' Fidel Castro en bola. (Hi naked Fidel Castro).

Answer (score 2):

En este tiempo de *memes* y tanta interconexión, continuamente surgen símbolos, imágenes para definir conceptos que ya subyacían pero que nadie se entretuvo en bautizar.

Últimamente se ve que se usa *fish face*:

[image]

E incluso urban dictionary ya habla de ello:

> [**Fish Face**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Fish%20Face&defid=1527046)
>
> 1) a phrase that mutually describes a deformed face that looks similarly like a fish, though no apparent fish like features can be seen. It is often associated with one who possesses extreme greediness and disease.
>
> 2) An incredibly greedy, insignificant person that leeches off others with fish like features and is disliked by most people. Approach with caution.
>
> 3) A mutant freak that greatly portrays greediness and sexual disgust. Extreme greediness is often associated with the organism and insignificance. Uses saliva and spit as a self defense mechanism

Ergo puede querer decir muchas cosas. En una [discusión de WordReference](http://forum.wordreference.com/threads/cara-de-pez.1551904/?hl=es) dicen:

> En Chile decimos "andar con cara de pescado" cuando alguien tiene cara de no estar disfrutando algo.
>   Por ejemplo, en una reunión social o una fiesta, si en un grupo todos conversan, se divierten y ríen y hay uno que notoriamente desentona, de él se dirá que "andaba o tenía cara de pescado".

Otro añade:

> In Argentina the usual is to say "cara de pescado/pescáo", and it means that the person is ugly, not necessarily stupid.

Por lo que es difícil determinar exactamente pero probablemente es una mezcla entre:

- Fealdad
- Cara de no estar del todo allí
- Un saludo tonto sin mayor connotación

Yo voto por la última, lo vería como un gesto cariñoso con una pizca de maldad.

Comment: Estoy seguro que los peces como tal no tienen nada que ver aquí. Es un saludo que busca ser simpático sin emitir un juicio en absoluto. Es decir, yo también votaría por la última opción.

Answer (score 2):

Ya publiqué un post con una respuesta pero acabo de hablar con una amiga mexicana y me propuso una alternativa:

Una expresión muy vulgar en México es "[Qué pex](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=que%20pex)". Significa "Qué pedo."

**Opción 1: What's up?**

Hola cara de pez = Hola [que pex](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=que%20pex) = Hola, ¿qué pedo? = What's up?

**Opción 2: Hola cara de pedo.**

Hola cara de pez = Hola cara de pex = Hola cara de pedo.

Answer (score 1):

Acaba de hacerse muy famoso (más bien *infame*) por viral un youtuber que "gastaba una broma" con un saludo parecido: "[caranchoa](http://www.elmundo.es/f5/comparte/2016/12/14/58517613268e3eda688b4612.html)" (cara [de] anchoa).

A pesar que se surgen nuevos modismos y expresiones todos los días, como norma básica yo te recomendaría desconfiar. Es posible que, en mayor o menor medida, con más o menos maldad, te esten intentando [*vacilar*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/11969/5481).

Desde luego no te está diciendo nada del tipo "Hola imbécil" u "Hola caraculo". En comparación "cara de pez" puede ser un vacile muy suave. Posiblemente tu interlocutor no sabe ni por qué los ha soltado o dicho así y no pretende ofender. Solo pretendía ser gracioso. Es posible además que tu interlocutor asuma cierto grado de complicidad entre los dos y espere "picarte" un poco con el comentario sin llegar a ofender, esperando (o forzándote) incluso a responder con algo más ingenioso.

Dudo mucho que la gente se salude así en ningún sitio (México u otro lado), ya sea con "cara de pez" o "cara de lo-que-sea". Si acaso será una moda pasajera o una tendencia entre los más jóvenes. De lo contrario cada vez que dos personas se encuentran en México se da un despliegue de ingenio ("Hola cara de esto; Buenos días cara de lo otro"). Sin mencionar que ni de lejos me imagino esto como algo formal, cotidiano o natural (imaginemos a dos importantes hombres de negocios, que se saludan con  "Hola cara de pez", o al conductor de autbús que da los buenos días a todos los pasajeros. La primera vez que te llaman "cara de pez" vale, ¡¡pero al trigesimoseptimo pasajero que te lo dice, le echas del autobús!!).

Con lo cual, es solo una pequeña broma. No pretendía en serio ofender.

Comment: Por si sirve de algo: [Que es el "albur"](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/3962/5481) y ["¿Cómo darme cuenta si alguien me esta albureando?"](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/4872/5481)

Comment: Estoy absolutamente de acuerdo